# jquery keyup delay is being ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, timeout, keyup

Ok perhaps someone could enlighten me as to what I am missing here guys. I have a text box which updates a jquery data table with ajax call based on user input. Obviously the desire is to only fire the ajax call when the user has finished typing.

However no matter what snippets I try from SO and elsewhere the timeout is ignored and the ajax fire immediately. I wonder if anyone might point me in the right direction.

```
    var timer;
$("#search_query").on('keyup', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);  //clear any interval on key up
    timer = setTimeout(alert("test"), 3000);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass a function to the timeout function as the first parameter. Now you're passing the result of the alert("test") call.

```
   var timer;
$("#search_query").on('keyup', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);  //clear any interval on key up
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ alert("test"); }, 3000);
});
```

This should work.

Comment: Arghh!! So simple, thanks so much for the help, it works perfectly now. I will accept in 8 minutes when SO allows me too. Have a good one.

Comment: Welcome, a pleasure to help.

Answer (score 0):

try this `setTimeout( 'you need to pass function here', 300 )`

```
var timer;
$("#search_query").on('keyup', function() {
    clearInterval(timer);  //clear any interval on key up
    timer = setTimeout(hello, 3000);
});

function hello(){ 
    alert("test"); 
}
```